# Clear out voted on suggested edits from my list

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits, clean-up

It would be great if suggested edits could be made to work similarly to the flag posts page - where once a post has been actioned by myself, it is removed from the list I see.

At the moment, if there are (say) 50 suggested edits and I approve/reject 20 and refresh the page, I need to go through the whole list and find the posts I have not worked on before.

Not that this is very onerous, but it does add that little bit of friction...

Comment: I have seen this before on meta... will see if I can fix it today ... I want to keep you productive :) ... btw .. as a top cleaner-upper ... have you had a play with the new /review tweaks ... any suggestions?

Comment: @waffles - Good to have a custom reject reason :). Like having the "improve" button right there.

Comment: more specifically http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions?s=1&pagesize=50&filter=day&customsort=reverseorder&no-random=1 (note the settings will become sticky to disable non random look at bottom)

Comment: @waffles - Sam, I don't normally use these pages, but this is very useful to keep track of where one is in the list :)

Comment: yeah I see that as a problem need to figure out a way to give the review pages more visibility

Comment: Let me know if my answer is good enough for a status-completed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually surprisingly tricky.

We count the number of suggestions in the queue and display that in the header. This number is cached heavily, we would like to avoid tacking on a query per user in the header. A global change would require that forcing us to change a global cache to a per-user cache.

Since this is a minor issue, I think that a simple amendment can get us most of the way.

I changed it so suggestions you **voted on** will now appear at the **end of the list**. Hopefully this gets us most of the way.

Comment: I'll go through it today and let you know how I find it - thanks for the effort.

Comment: This certainly makes things easier, by all means status-completed.

Comment: What about collapsing them to one line like the ones I just voted on (as last voter)?